# c++Type alias names for static member variables in template classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-alias

So I've created a little demo code to show my question ([view on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/X7x4GN)):

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct Test {
    using Vec = std::vector<T>;
    static Vec data; 
};

template <class T>
Test<T>::Vec data = {};
```

This gives the following error:

```
<source>:10:1: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'Test<T>::Vec'

Test<T>::Vec data = {};

^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've tried a few different permutations with no luck.

For instance, this version seems to work with gcc and in Visual Studio 2017 ([view on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/XqbeCt)):

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct Test {
    template <class U>
    using Vec = std::vector<T>;
    static Vec<T> data;
};

template <class T>
Test<T>::Vec<T> data = {};
```

However, clang doesn't like it.

Then stuff like ([view on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/_Z9CZ9)):

```
#include <array>

struct SomeStruct {
    static constexpr auto max_size() {
        return sizeof(SomeStruct);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct Test {
    using Arr = std::array<unsigned, SomeStruct::max_size()>;
    static Arr data;
};

template <class T>
Test<T>::Arr data = {};
```

Nothing likes, but then if you change Arr to ([view on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/-U2vM-)):

```
template <class T>
struct Test {
    template <class U>
    using Arr = std::array<unsigned, SomeStruct::max_size()>;
    static Arr<T> data;
};

template <class T>
Test<T>::Arr<T> data = {};
```

gcc and Visual Studio are happy, but clang still doesn't like it.

So my question is, what is the rule of thumb when creating a type alias for static member variables, and how would I go about fixing the above so they work properly on all compilers? (c++17 and above is fine)

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: You need `typename Test<T>::Vec data = {};` since `Vec` depends on `T`. (FWIW the error message tells you this).

Comment: Another solution is to use `decltype(Test<T>::data) data = {};`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the example, I had kept interpreting the missing typename as if I needed an additional `template<typename X>` in-front, rather than just the keyword `typename`.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot which option would you say is the more current of the two?

Comment: @HexCrown so you need `typename` here because in your function `vec`  is a [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)

Comment: @HexCrown I woudln't say it's more current, use what you prefer. Also, your code will simply work in C++20. They removed the need for typename and template in many places.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Ah, I'm still stuck using 17, but thats good to know :D